# How to get client Ip address Flask | visiter IP | unable to find client Ipaddress

Tags: python, flask

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKAwn.png)

Code:

```
ip_addr = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
print(f'ipaddr --> {ip_addr}')
print(request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' , request.remote_addr))
print(f'Remote Addr --> {request.remote_addr}' )
```

I try all this in order to get the client ip-addr but don't know why there locahost is coming.

Please Elaborate and guide.

Comment: Are you sending a request from a terminal running in your computer to a server running in your computer? Because that's what `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` mean. If you make a request from your computer to `127.0.0.1`, the traffic doesn't go outside your computer. Therefore, the IP is "this computer"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine for getting client IP. Try to run your application with different any host (`flask run -h 0.0.0.0`) and access it from different machine on the same network, you should see it's IP then.